# WebMethod response header is 500 internal server error but the response body contains expected data

Tags: c#, asp.net, webmethod

Bit of an odd one so im hoping someone can help. I have a c# WebMethod running inside an ASMX file. I am calling this method from another application via JQuery $ajax.

The asmx is running inside a web application that has had its max json length set to the int32 limit.

I would say 1/50 or so requests results in my error function (the ajax error function) being run due to the response from the server bringing back the following:

```
Key Value
Response    HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Cache-Control   private
Content-Type    application/json; charset=utf-8
Server  Microsoft-IIS/8.5
jsonerror   true
X-AspNet-Version    4.0.30319
X-Powered-By    ASP.NET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers    Content-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Methods    GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS
Date    Tue, 09 Aug 2016 14:25:11 GMT
Content-Length  91
```

But if i then look in the response body a complete wholly formed json object is being returned.

As i say 49/50 times the method returns 200 with the same data that is visible when it does 500, anyone have any ideas as to where i could start investigating as to why its sporadic considering that the web method takes no parameters.

The WebMethod is:

```
[WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(UseHttpGet = true, ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public List<BasicUIN> ReturnBasicUINList()
        {

            try
            {
                return BasicUIN.PopulateBasicUINS(true);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Edit:

Just wanted to add that after looking at the request in Chrome and Fiddler it would seem that Internet Explorer Network tab has been lying to me! The response body doesn't contain a fully formed list of my expected data, but instead contains an error message, however the message and stack trace are both "". I have turned off custom error messages but still receive no stack trace back in the resulting request when it does 500, only a message of 'there was an error processing your request'.

Any ideas how i can get the full error message?

Update2: I have managed to obtain the full error:

```
{"Message":"Invalid attempt to read when no data is present.","StackTrace":"   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.CheckDataIsReady(Int32 columnIndex, Boolean allowPartiallyReadColumn, Boolean permitAsync, String methodName)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryReadColumn(Int32 i, Boolean setTimeout, Boolean allowPartiallyReadColumn)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetValueInternal(Int32 i)\r\n   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetValue(Int32 i)\r\n   at Central.WS.ViewModels.BasicUIN.PopulateBasicUINS(Boolean includeCranfield, Boolean includeArchived)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}
```

However, im not sure how this can be the case when its the same data being returned every time, the method which populates my object is:

```
 public static List<BasicUIN> PopulateBasicUINS(bool redacted = true, bool includeArchived = false)
        {
            List<BasicUIN> UINList = new List<BasicUIN>();
            SQLDataLayer dal =
                new SQLDataLayer(
                    System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["xxxx"].ToString());
            dal.AddParameter("redacted", redacted, DbType.Boolean);
            dal.AddParameter("includeArchived", includeArchived, DbType.Boolean);

            IDataReader dreader = dal.GetResultSet("usp_xxxxx", CommandType.StoredProcedure);


            while (dreader.Read())
            {
                BasicUIN uinEntry = new BasicUIN();
                uinEntry.ID = (int) dreader["idRefUIN"];
                uinEntry.Code = dreader["varUIN"].ToString();
                uinEntry.Name = dreader["varDescription"].ToString();
                UINList.Add(uinEntry);
            }

            dreader.Dispose();
            return UINList;
        }
```

Given that i populate objects only inside the while loop im a bit puzzled?

Update4: So i managed to re-create the issue when sql server profiler was running, it would seem that when the error occurred the 'RowCounts' column displays a different number compared to when it didn't error:

so normally: 27194
error: 25928

now i know that RowCount is just the rows that are 'touched' and not actually the number of rows returned...is this just a red herring?

Comment: First, remove the try catch. Let the exception bubble up naturally. Second, show the part of your web config for error messages.

Comment: Thanks, i have done that and have updated the original with the extra information.